# Display elements of a <ul> in two columns

Tags: javascript, jquery

Someone please help me to change current function to display elements in two columns,

```
 function nextCode(flag)
 {
  var code = codes[flag];
  $('.headers').html(''+code[0]+'');
  var sum;for(var j=1;j<=code.length;j++)
  {
    sum+="<li>"+code[j]+"</li>";
  }
  sum="<ul>"+sum+"</ul>";
  $('.options').html(''+sum+'');
 }
```

This is generating a list in single column, But i want to display them in two columns..
Please help me on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will this do your work?

```
function nextCode(flag)
            {
                var code = codes[flag];
                code = ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5"];    //Testing purpose data
                $('.headers').html(''+code[0]+'');
                var sum="";
                var sum1="";

                for(var j=0;j < code.length;j++) { //Iteration changes required in code
                    if(j%2 > 0) {
                        sum += "<li>" + code[j] + "</li>";
                    } else {
                        sum1 += "<li>" + code[j] + "</li>";
                    }
                }

            sum = "<ul style=\"position: relative; float: left;\">" + sum1 + "</ul>" + "<ul style=\"position: relative; float: left;\">" + sum + "</ul>";
            $('.options').html(''+sum+'');
            }
            </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Float your li's with css. Give them a specific width's and you should be good.

```
.options ul {
    width:300px;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.options ul li {
   float:left;
   width:150px;
   list-style:none;
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no facility for this in HTML or CSS, so you just need to manage two or more columns in memory, something like this:

```
var list_items = ['Bacon', 'Cheese', 'Beer', 'Beef', 'Ham', 'Honey', 'Tuna', 'Coffee'];
var list_len = list_items.length;
var num_columns = 2;
var column_size = Math.ceil(list_len/num_columns);
var html = ['<ul>'];
var push = Array.prototype.push;

for (var i=0; i < list_len; i++) {
  if (i && i % column_size === 0) html.push('</ul><ul>');      
  push.apply(html,['<li>',list_items[i],'</li>']);
}
html.push('</ul>');

$('.destination').html(html.join(''));
```